# Reference request: Recent progress on the conjugacy problem for torsion-free one-relator groups?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory, decidability

I am aware that the Spelling Theorem of B. B. Newman implies that one-relator groups with torsion are hyperbolic, and thus have a solvable conjugacy problem. My understanding is that for one-relator groups without torsion, the conjugacy problem is still open, though the most recent reference I have for this is over 20 years old.

Has there been any recent developments in this area? Any references for work in this area would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is still open. There was a claimed proof in the 90s, but I believe this is generally accepted to contain gaps.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda That's interesting. Is [this paper from 1992](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-9730-4_3) the claimed proof you are referring to?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. At the [WOW](https://archive.uea.ac.uk/~fga12juu/WOW.html), I am told the consensus was that the problem remains open.

Comment: As someone who has actively tried to solve it, I'm certainly under the impression that the problem is open. I'm interested to hear about the claimed solution of Juhasz, which I didn't know about. I notice that the linked paper is only a (self-confessed) sketch. I wonder if a more detailed account was ever written?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is still considered an open problem. I thought I'd flesh out a few aspects. A solution was claimed in 1992 by [Juhasz](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4613-9730-4_3), but it seems to have failed to convince experts. The small cancellation theory involved in the proof seems to be very intricate, though I am not aware of any concrete example of a gap in the proof. Perhaps someone can fill me in on this.

At the Winter One-relator Workshop at the University of East Anglia two years ago, in 2018, (see [WOW](https://archive.uea.ac.uk/%7Efga12juu/WOW.html), this very question was brought up. I was not there myself, but it was organised by my supervisor; I myself asked him this question not long ago, and he conveyed that the consensus was that the problem remained open.

As another example from the literature, in [these excellent notes](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/OneRelator.pdf) by Andrew Putman, one reads "Whether or not torsion-free one-relator groups have a solvable conjugacy problem is a famous and difficult open question". I am not sure exactly when these notes are from, but certainly after 2016. So: the problem remains open.

Answer (score 9):

Yuhasz approach was to prove that every one-relator group satisfies certain version of small cancelation condition and hence has solvable conjugacy problem. Of course if the relator satisfies $C'(1/6)$ the group is hyperbolic and we are done. I think from what he proved the CAT(0)
 conditions $C(3)-T(6)$ and $C(4)-T(4)$ are Ok too but I do not think all cases are covered in his paper. It was long since I looked at his text, so I may forget something.
Victor Guba knows the text well.